# how to keep track which file is uploaded in ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, ng2-file-upload

I have many files and input tags lets say I have these files i.e profileImage (JPEG), Certificate (pdf),ID card (.docx) . I am using [this link](https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/)
 for file uploading file on server. here is only **input tag**.

my server will response with their address of file after being uploaded (/content/profile.JPEG). I want to keep track which file is uploaded at that time so i can manage their call back paths on front end.
like I can save separate address for profile image and so on for certificate and id card. 
[image: here is image]

Comment: Hey, I have same problem. Did you get the answer for this?

Comment: I have used the angular fork.join for this @Neel

Comment: Thanks. can you show your code block please? I am trying to put file uploader under a loop so I am wondering how to track which uploader selected which file. Can you help please?

Comment: you are sending file object to backend ? @Neel

Comment: and hitting url to save it on server ?

Comment: I am not using this module ng_file_upload. I am sending it through form data

Comment: I am using ng2-file-upload. Wondering how to do this with this library

Comment: I think you cant do this with this library :p I've done through form data